# PuTTy background processing executing IDL scripts

Tags: linux, putty, idl, nohup

I'd like to start an extensive IDL process which will be run on a linux based server.

Given a normal a procedure like this:

- open PuTTy
- move to right directory
- compile IDL scripts (1 main script executing 2 others)
- run main script.

Now I would like to do that in the background. After some Google research I found out that it is adivisable to use the nohup-command. But I don't know what this command should look like including my scripts....

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

nohup command can be used to run any job in background which you run in foreground.
The syntax for it is :
nohup your_script &

You can use the fg to bring this job to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

To detach your current process you can use two solutions:

## `nohup`

Run:

1. `nohup ./process </dev/null &>log.txt &`
2. `disown` to detach the process from your pseudo-TTY, so that when you exit, the process doesn't terminate.

## `screen`

With `nohup` you lose all control over the process and all you can do is to kill it. It might be a better idea to use `screen` which lets you gain access to the detached "TTY" again:

1. Run `screen`; `screen` will spawn a new shell.
2. Run `./process` normally
3. Now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>D</kbd> - you will get back to your parent shell
4. You can logout now
5. After you login again, you can view the task again with `screen -r`

Comment: Ok the screen also seems to fit pretty good but when I try to enter "screen" to PuTTy it simply says "command not found"....is this some kind of package that needs to be installed?

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to install it on the server you connect to. It should be a matter of `apt-get install screen` or `pacman -S screen` or similar, depending on your package manager.